# How to make a filling progress circle in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-animation

I need to make a progress circle like this:[image]

I have created a CAShapeLayer for the circle, and animate its strokeEnd property like this:

```
pieShape = CAShapeLayer()
pieShape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(29, 29), radius: 27.0, startAngle: CGFloat(startAngle), endAngle: CGFloat(endAngle), clockwise: true).CGPath
pieShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
pieShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
pieShape.lineWidth = 4.0

self.layer.addSublayer(pieShape)


let countDownAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        countDownAnimation.duration = durationInSeconds
        countDownAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
        countDownAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
        countDownAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
        countDownAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        self.pieShape.strokeStart = 1.0
        self.pieShape.addAnimation(countDownAnimation, forKey: "drawCircleAnimation")
```

But, this not what I want. I need to animate the circle filling, not only the border. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about your `strokeStart` of `1.0`. I would have left that alone. Also, your `NSNumber` instantiation is unnecessary (e.g. you can use `0.0` rather than `NSNumber(float: 0.0)`), as Swift appears to automatically make `NSNumber` objects for you...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to cheat, and animate just the stroke, but make it appear to be animating the fill of the circle. For example, if you wanted a circle of radius `30`, use a `radius` of `15` instead, but a `lineWidth` of `30`, so that the stroke effectively covers from the center to the desired radius of `30`.

[image]

There are more complicated methods using `CADisplayLink`, and updating it yourself, but the above is pretty easy way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Clever! I’m surprised the stroke handles that correctly.