# UIBezierPath not updated as expected

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect, uibezierpath

This is my code for my custom view:

```
class CircleView3: UIView {
    let endPoint = 270.0
    var index = 0.0
    var startPoint: Double {
        get{
            index++
            let div = 360.0/60.0
            let vaule = div * index
            return 290.0 + vaule
        }
    }

    func degreesToRadians (number: Double) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(number) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
          super.drawRect(rect)
        let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(startPoint)
        let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(endPoint)
        print("start = \(startAngleRadiant)")
        print("end = \(endAngleRadiant)")
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(center)
        path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: self.frame.height/2.2, startAngle: startAngleRadiant, endAngle: endAngleRadiant, clockwise: true)
        path.addLineToPoint(center)
        let strokeColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 155.0/255.0, green: 137.0/255.0, blue: 22.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        strokeColor.setFill()  //strokeColor.setStroke()
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

I am drawing a circle. I call the `setNeedsDisplay` function from a view controller each second. I am supposed to draw a circle that is reducing its start and end point each second, but the circle keep its last line (position) even after the update. Plus the circle is not filled with my color, just the line is filled.

http://www.mediafire.com/watch/xnkew5eu8da5wub/IMG_0066.MOV

#### Update

I print the start values in `drawRect`, and the values are correct:

```
start  = 293.6
start  = 297.2
start  = 300.8
start  = 304.4
start  = 308.0
start  = 311.6
start  = 315.2
start  = 318.8
start  = 322.4
start  = 326.0
start  = 329.6
start  = 333.2
start  = 336.8
start  = 340.4
```

of course these are the values before changing them to radians.

#### Update 2

After I call the `strokeColor.setFill()` the situation is better, but I still see the problem. Please see this new video:

http://www.mediafire.com/watch/nb1b3v2zgqletwb/IMG_0069.MOV

Comment: You need to say strokeColor.setFill() before path.fill() to have it fill. You should post the code of the timing function where you're calling setNeedsDisplay

Comment: @beyowulf okay the set fill solved the fill problem, but i still in my main problem, why do you need the code that calls the setneed display? that code does nothing except calling the setneedsdisplay for the view. whick will call my draw rect function inside the CircleView3

Comment: It seems like the path is getting drawn on top of itself over and over again. Are you doing anything with the view's layer? Or creating the view and adding it to your view controller's view in the timer function?

Comment: @beyowulf no no i don't do anything, after setting the set fill on the colore, the situation imporoved a little bit, i am try to upload a new video,

Comment: @beyowulf i add a new video, you look for me?

Comment: Have you looked at @vacawama's answer? I did the same thing he did and got the same result. Are you saying something like setNeedsDisplayInRect?

Comment: @beyowulf so it works with you? my code? i don't call set needs display in my view, i called it from outside (inside the view constroller). please help

Comment: I used the code @vacawama posted he's calling circleView.setNeedsDisplay() from the view controller that has the circle view as a subview.

Comment: @sarah Do you really want it updated periodically, or do you want a smooth, continuous animation. If so, you can use `CABasicAnimation` to [animate the drawing of a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32898165/1271826), and it's much easier than the code above. FYI, if you stay with the above code, I'd advise (a) don't set the angle from a calculation stemming from `index++`, but rather use timestamps; and (b) consider using `CADisplayLink` rather than `NSTimer`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14962473/1271826) is for a different animation, but illustrates the concept.

Comment: @Rob hello, i didn't know about any of that CABasicAnimation. and CADisplayLink, I will study the links you said, and try to understand. thank you always very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what its worth, I put your code in a project and I see a shrinking circle as `setNeedsDisplay` is called on the customView.  It does not draw like your video.

Here is my additional code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: CircleView3!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, selector: "updateCircle", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateCircle() {
        circleView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: that is i dont understand. do work with u? i in my view controller have this  formatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss"
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire() and the function update is :   circleTimerView.setNeedsDisplay() where circleTimerView is the outlet of the view. u understand me? i put a new video

Comment: I'm using your exact `CircleView3` code from above and my code as shown and your view draws correctly.  There must be something else different about your setup.  Try creating a new project using just my code and your `CircleView3` and you should see it works properly.

Comment: i am trying to see the prboem, first i don't knwo why this black backgrond is happen. second, really i dont do anything anything else in my code, i just all the set needs display.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  I'm setting the background color of my custom view in Interface Builder.  Black or white, the circle looks fine.

Comment: i am using Version 7.1 (7B91b) . i dont know what to say, i still have the problem, i hope someone help me or you please help me

Comment: i write code that works with people's machine not my machine? ? how that possible

Comment: I'm using version 7.1.1.  I highly doubt that makes a difference, but you might want to update to be sure.  Have you tried creating a new project with just my code?  Copy the `CircleView3` code from this question.  It would take all of 5 minutes.

Comment: i found the soulition , i did this circleTimerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0) on my view controler, i changed the background to while. and that works good, i am confused though the problem solved, but i am confused about the reason.

Comment: I'm glad it's working.  I don't know why it was failing for your in the first place.  `circleTimerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()` should be sufficient though.  `UIColor` is inferred by Swift, and the default alpha is `1.0`.